# Round date long value

Tags: java, datetime, rounding, epoch

In my Java project I used date in `long` and for example it is `12136219` and by creating `Date` object as below:

```
long time = 12136219;
Date date = new Date(time);
```

and it represent date as `Thu Jan 01 04:22:16 CET 1970`. How can I round date (in long representation) to minutes ?

For example I want achieve `Thu Jan 01 04:22:00 CET 1970` if the seconds are `<30` and `Thu Jan 01 04:23:00 CET 1970` if the seconds are `>=30` but I want round this `long time = 12136219` representation. Any idea?

Comment: `time` are just miliseconds since Jan 1 1970. So you would have to convert it into seconds and round it there according to docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date-long-

Still, I can't see any point in doing so. Why won't you do this in after conversion to Date?

Comment: I want to do this BEFORE convert do Date. I Used convert to date only for example what I want achieve.

Comment: I meant, count seconds. Like Scott mentioned in his answer, You get milliseconds, a minute is 60*1000 milliseconds, so this should give you enough idea to deal with this.

Comment: Excuse me for asking, do those milliseconds really represent a date and time in 1970, or are they really a duration (an amount of elapsed time, for example)?

Comment: @OleV.V.: It is milliseconds *since* the start of 1/1/1970, not necessarily *in* 1970.

Comment: (A) If you *really* want fair rounding, you would use the [*Bankers’ rounding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) specified in the [`RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_DOWN) object. Your [*Schoolhouse rounding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_up)  method is biased towards rounding up to larger (later) number. (B) Note that truncation is quite common in date-time handling rather than bothering with rounding, at least in the business world. The java.time classes support truncation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since time is
"milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT"
You could calculate the seconds like this:

```
secondsInMillis = time % (60 * 1000) //get remainder (modulo): seconds * milliseconds
if (secondsInMillis < 30000) {
  time -= secondsInMillis; //round down
} else {
  time += (60000 - secondsInMillis); // round up
}
```

Comment: Or just `time = 60 * 1000 * Math.round(time / (60.0 * 1000.0));`.

Answer (score 4):

Don’t reinvent the wheel. Use `java.time.Instant` for representing an instant in time:

```
    Instant i = Instant.ofEpochMilli(time);
    i = i.plusSeconds(30).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
```

`Instant` doesn’t offer rounding, only truncation. However, adding 30 seconds and then truncating gives you what you want. If you need your milliseconds back, it’s easy:

```
    time = i.toEpochMilli();
    System.out.println(time);
```

With the number from your question this prints

```
12120000
```

(This is equal to an instant of 1970-01-01T03:22:00Z, or 1970-01-01T04:22+01:00[Europe/Paris] in CET, or the expected rounding down of your `04:22:16 CET`.)

PS I am quite convinced that a library like [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) will offer rounding so you don’t need the trick of adding and truncating. Unfortunately I don’t have the experience to give you the details.

Answer (score 3):

When you create a `Date` from a `long`, the long represents the number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970.  There are 60*1000 milliseconds in a minute.  That should be enough information to fashion the rounding algorithm you need.

Answer (score 1):

Reset seconds and milliseconds with [Calendar.set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int,%20int))

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTES, calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND) >= 30 ? 1 : 0)
currentDate = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

> Sets the given calendar field to the given value. The value is not interpreted by this method regardless of the leniency mode.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it on the Date object. There is no easy way to calculate it in the time epoch, because of various difficulties including the length of a month (28, 29, 30 or 31).

Comment: What does the day of the month have to do with rounding to the nearest minute?